# Google chrome DOMException: Permission denied by system for navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, webcam, getusermedia

It's November of 2019, this JavaScript code works in 
FireFox (70.0.1 (64-bit)), 
Safari (13.0.2 (15608.2.30.1.1)), 
Opera (Version:65.0.3467.48), 
On a Windows Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (64-bit), this code works.
but NOT in MacOS Google Chrome (Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

```
navigator
.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})
.then(stream => {
    console.log("success!")
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log("e: ", e);
});
```

In Chrome's console, I got: *DOMException: Permission denied*
After much googling, I haven't found anything up to date. How exactly do we use JS to request camera access in Chrome?

Comment: Check your settings that you didn't accidentally reject or disable the use permission at some point: Settings -> Site Settings -> Camera

Comment: If I specifically set the site's camera settings to "Block", I get the same exception. It should be set to "Ask".

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I checked, it's set to "Ask". Still I got the message, indeed the same message that would show up when that very setting is "Blocked" as mentioned by Ernest. You will see what I mean if you paste my code into Chrome console.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/1191

Also does this page ask for a microphone?
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/audio/

Comment: @Ernest,  webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/audio  does work fine in my Chrome, but when I use the source code locally, I go NotAllowedError. Finally the solution lies in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Camera & Microphone as jib mentioned below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since MacOS Mojave, camera and microphone [require OS permissions](https://blog.addpipe.com/camera-and-microphone-access-in-macos-mojave/).

This applies to all non-Apple products, including all browsers other than Safari.

Check System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Camera & Microphone. Make sure Chrome is listed and has a checkbox.

You should have gotten a special OS prompt about this the first time Chrome tried to access them. But if it accidentally got blocked somehow, you won't ever be prompted again.

Comment: I am getting the error on a Windows machine, inside an app that loads an HTML page containing the native camera feature code.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I did not realize the project I was working in was adding a security header, blocking the possibility of microphone use:

`Feature-Policy "microphone 'none'; geolocation 'none'"`

Comment: it helped it me! and I have remove mcrophone key from header!

Comment: This fixed it for me too - there was a HeaderPolicyCollection() that was injecting this to all headers in my ASP.NET application

Answer (score 5):

#### Windows 11 - Microphone Privacy Settings fix

From the other solutions it sounds like a variety of issues could be causing this problem. For me (Windows 11, Google Chrome) this issue was caused by my microphone being disabled in my Windows privacy settings.

To fix, click Start and search for "Microphone Privacy Settings". In the control panel that pops up, switch "Microphone access" to on.

Comment: thank $god I found this!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was occurring for me even though the site in question did not appear under blocked sites on the microphone setting page.

I had to go to Site Settings -> View Permissions and Data stored across all sites -> Find my Site -> Click Reset Permissions to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> **Feature-Policy** has now been renamed to Permissions-Policy in the spec, and this article will eventually be updated to reflect that change. [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy)

In my case, I set a header with an empty parentheses

```
Permissions-Policy: microphone=()
```

and according to this [document](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/main/permissions-policy-explainer.md#example-6---disable-a-feature-entirely-with-an-http-header), it disables the access.

> The empty allowlist ensures that the feature is disabled in all contexts everywhere.

So changing the header to

```
Permissions-Policy: microphone=(self)
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, on your browser media is disabled,
try to enable your media source video/audio on your chrome browser

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error in a slightly different case (on Windows 10, Chrome):
I was running a local server and accessed my own website from
`http://127.0.0.1:5500/`.
The solution was to access it from
`http://localhost:5500/`
instead.